# iPython notebook - Memory Error when loading CIFAR - 10 dataset

Tags: python-2.7, memory, svm

I'm currently following the Convolutional neural network course of Stanford: http://cs231n.github.io/. I'm running the assignments on a Lenovo SL500 with 2GBs of RAM. But when I load the Cifar-10 dataset using the following code:

```
import cPickle as pickle
import numpy as np
import os
from scipy.misc import imread

def load_CIFAR_batch(filename):
  """ load single batch of cifar """
  with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    datadict = pickle.load(f)
    X = datadict['data']
    Y = datadict['labels']
    X = X.reshape(10000, 3, 32, 32).transpose(0,2,3,1).astype("float")
    Y = np.array(Y)
    return X, Y

def load_CIFAR10(ROOT):
  """ load all of cifar """
  xs = []
  ys = []
  for b in range(1,6):
    f = os.path.join(ROOT, 'data_batch_%d' % (b, ))
    X, Y = load_CIFAR_batch(f)
    xs.append(X)
    ys.append(Y)    
  Xtr = np.concatenate(xs)
  Ytr = np.concatenate(ys)
  del X, Y
  Xte, Yte = load_CIFAR_batch(os.path.join(ROOT, 'test_batch'))
  return Xtr, Ytr, Xte, Yte
```

Actually here is the part that calls the functions:

```
# Load the raw CIFAR-10 data.
cifar10_dir = 'cs231n/datasets/cifar-10-batches-py'
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = load_CIFAR10(cifar10_dir)

# As a sanity check, we print out the size of the training and test data.
print 'Training data shape: ', X_train.shape
print 'Training labels shape: ', y_train.shape
print 'Test data shape: ', X_test.shape
print 'Test labels shape: ', y_test.shape
```

I get this error:

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-76ab1121c87e> in <module>()
      1 # Load the raw CIFAR-10 data.
      2 cifar10_dir = 'cs231n/datasets/cifar-10-batches-py'
----> 3 X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = load_CIFAR10(cifar10_dir)
      4 
      5 # As a sanity check, we print out the size of the training and test data.

C:\Users\son\assignment1\cs231n\data_utils.py in load_CIFAR10(ROOT)
     20   for b in range(1,6):
     21     f = os.path.join(ROOT, 'data_batch_%d' % (b, ))
---> 22     X, Y = load_CIFAR_batch(f)
     23     xs.append(X)
     24     ys.append(Y)

C:\Users\son\assignment1\cs231n\data_utils.py in load_CIFAR_batch(filename)
     10     X = datadict['data']
     11     Y = datadict['labels']
---> 12     X = X.reshape(10000, 3, 32, 32).transpose(0,2,3,1).astype("float")
     13     Y = np.array(Y)
     14     return X, Y

MemoryError:
```

And the thing is the memory usage quickly rises to 2GB ! Even though the CIFAR-10 dataset is only about 177MB! 
[image]

I have tried loading only a single batch, and it worked, but I had to be very careful not to mess up any step (don't run the same cell twice, even if it does not appears to be running,...). Does anyone have a solution for this? Thank you very much!

UPDATE: In the `load_CIFAR_batch` function, if I comment out the reshape line: `# X = X.reshape(10000, 3, 32, 32).transpose(0,2,3,1).astype("float")`
then the program is able to load:
[image]
So maybe the reason my program couldn't run was because of the reshape line, which creates a copy of X and Y therefore doubling the data. Is this hypothesis correct and if it does, what should I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the size of your data, this line

```
X = X.reshape(10000, 3, 32, 32).transpose(0,2,3,1).astype("float")
```

tells us that each batch of data is `10000*3*32*32` which is a bit over 30 million floating point numbers. The `float` data type is actually the same as `float64`, which means 8 bytes per number.
This means that each batch takes up, at least, 240 MB.
You load 6 of these (5 training + 1 test) which in total yield something closer to 1.4 GB of data.
If the dataset is indeed closer to 180 MB on disk, it seems to be compressed pretty well :)

As I see it you have two (non-mutual) options:

1. If possible, run the training one batch at a time. You hint that you have already tried this.
2. Depending on the type of problem double accuracy (64-bit floats) might be more than what you need. So you could try to change the line above to `float32` instead of `float`. This would effectively cut memory requirement to half.
   But **it might also screw up calculations** unless you are not careful.
3. Buy more RAM or run on another machine. If you go further with machine learning this *will* be a problem for you at some point. 2GB is weak by pretty much any standard, and in the machine learning world it is close to nothing.

Comment: Can't I use virtual memory? (I tried to but it didn't work and i don't know why :( )

Comment: I have updated the answer, can you please tell me if what I think is correct? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem.

I solved it by cutting down datasets by modifying the `load_CIFAR10()` in data_utils.py.

```
def load_CIFAR10(ROOT):
  """ load all of cifar """
  xs = []
  ys = []
  for b in range(1, 2): 
    # not to load all the data files, just 3 or less to test
    f = os.path.join(ROOT, 'data_batch_%d' % (b, ))
    X, Y = load_CIFAR_batch(f)
    # other codes...
```